# Find records with same values and set them to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set avatar_id to nil in records where it's the same as my current record self.avatar_id and it's the same type.

```
class AvatarPart < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :clear_avatar_body

  def clear_avatar_body
    used = AvatarPart.where(ap_type: self.ap_type, avatar_id: self.avatar_id).first
    if used
      used.avatar_id = nil
      used.save
    end
  end
end
```

Similar solution in rails console works fine. But in the model it doesn't do anything or one of my similar .each do solution ended in an infinite loop.
Should I move this to controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `update_all`. Something like this

```
AvatarPart.where(ap_type: self.ap_type, avatar_id: self.avatar_id).update_all(avatar_id: nil)
```

Comment: I'm testing this in console btw.

Comment: using this with before_save it works! edit: cahgned question to use before_save

Comment: I believe a transaction block can do more exact thing. Unless there is a chance, AvatartPart can be assigned to some other record as well. Just shared my thoughts.